# Как скопировать данные из одной таблицы в другую (чтобы обновился) в PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Как скопировать данные из одной таблицы в другую при этом когда обнаружется уже существующие данные он их не скопировал, а просто пропустил. Например: у меня есть боевая таблица (внутри есть база старая) и тестовая таблица. Есть новая база счетов. Я сначала заливаю в тестовую таблицу. а потом от тестовой в боевую скопирую (сейчас пытаюсь это сделать, но получаю ошибку уже сушествует). Вот мой скрипт:

```
insert into cu(****,****,****)
select ******* from test_cu
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас заголовок вопроса расходится с описанием. Всё-таки надо обновлять или пропускать?

Пропускать строки с конфликтами по уникальных ограничениям просто. Начиная с postgresql 9.5 есть дополнительное выражение `on conflict` [в синтаксисе `insert`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-insert.html)

```
insert into cu(****,****,****)
select ******* from test_cu
on conflict do nothing;
```

И всё. Если у вас postgresql более старой версии - весьма советую планировать обновление. Версия 9.4 подходит к концу своего срока поддержки ([по плану](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) последний выпуск исправлений ошибок будет 13 февраля 2020 года), более старые не поддерживаются уже. Впрочем, если не критична конкурентность, то выкрутиться можно малыми силами:

```
insert into cu(****,****,****)
select ******* from test_cu
where not exists (select null from cu where cu.pk_field = test_cu.pk_field)
```

Если необходимо обновлять - то есть вопрос, что и как именно необходимо обновлять. Можно добавлять записи и обновлять дубликаты: это опять же `on conflict` ноуже `do update` действие. Может быть вам нужно обновлять только совпадающие строк - тогда в помощь синтаксис `update .. from`, который может обновлять таблицу используя некоторую выборку данных.

Comment: Идеальный ответ! Спасибо!

Comment: Извиняюсь, но при выполнении кода 
insert into cu(****,****,****)
select ******* from test_cu
on conflict do nothing;

всех пропускает...есть 1000 строка в тесте а в оригинале 94...т.е он должен добавить из тестового 6 строк которые отсутствует, в оригинал

Comment: Что insert вернул в ответ? Проверьте в psql

Comment: Затронуто 0 записей...